how many roots can we have for equation $e^{a_1x}+e^{a_2x}+...+e^{a_nx}=ne^{cx}$?
Solve equation: $$\sum_{n\in\{1,...m\}}(-1)^ne^{-c_nx}=0$$ where $c_n$ are positive constants.
Is it true that such equation can have at most two real roots?
Sum of exponential functions have at most two roots? Similar equation: $\sum_n (-1)^nc_n^x=0$, has at most two roots.
For example, equation $e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}-e^{-x}-e^{-5x}=0$ has two roots: $0$ and $0.28$.
If not true, what is an example? (Solution given by Cediwelli in commetns)
Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227539/number-of-real-roots-of-an-exponential-polynomial
The initial question is, considering the equations: $$e^{a_1x}+e^{a_2x}+...+e^{a_nx}=ne^{cx}$$
, how many roots can we have? The question above is just a generalization of my initial question.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
